# How to import a csv file using @ as delimiter with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv, adodb

I am trying to load data from a csv file in Excel with VBA using ADODB.
I have a function to return a Connection object.

```
Private Function OpenConnection(dataSource As String) As ADODB.Connection
    Set OpenConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    With OpenConnection
        .ConnectionTimeout = 5
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & dataSource & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited(,)"";Persist Security Info=False"

        Debug.Print "trying to connect: " & .ConnectionString
        .Open
    End With
End Function
```

And then I just print the data.

```
Public Sub Test_Import()
    Dim conn As ADODB.connection, records As ADODB.Recordset

    Set connection = OpenConnection(foldername)
    Set records = connection.Execute("Select * from data.txt")

    Debug.Print records.Fields(0)
End Sub
```

If I use commas it works fine but in the end I will have to use a file that is separated by **'@'** symbols and which I cannot convert to using **','** because of missing write permissions.
Copying and changing the file somewhere else is unfortunately also not an option.

Now I changed `FMT=Delimited(,)` to `FMT=Delimited(@)` in the function `OpenConnection` and instead of returning the first column value `a1`, the full line `a1@b1@c1` is returned.

Is **'@'** not supported as a delimiting string? Or did I miss something?

Comment: See if [THIS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8d4463ae-9bc6-4445-87aa-bbfa60d0ae1b/using-jetoledb40-for-openning-csv-files?forum=accessdev) helps?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: thank you, it works.
I'll add the answer soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @SiddharthRout for the solution and the link to [a thread at windows dev center](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8d4463ae-9bc6-4445-87aa-bbfa60d0ae1b/using-jetoledb40-for-openning-csv-files?forum=accessdev).

The problem was that in the connection string one cannot set the delimiting string but only specify that the file is delimited using a specific character. `FMT=Delimited(@)` is treated just the same as `FMT=Delimited` or `FMT=Delimited(,)`.

I had to create a file **schema.ini** in the folder that contains the csv-file (*data.txt*) where I had to enter:

```
[data.txt]
Format = Delimited(@)
```

The schema.ini file will be parsed and the delimiter is read correctly and everything works *(as long as I don't change any file names)*.

I also found [another source at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx) that explains how to set the delimiting string (using either the registry or the mentioned *schema.ini*) and also includes Tabstops and fixed length separated files.

Answer (score 1):

@marcw - You are awesome.
To help You guys more - You don't have to create manually this file.
If You are using Filedialog it can look like this:

```
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False       ' Select only 1 file
    .InitialFileName = strPath      ' File location
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub    ' Quit when user cancels
    myFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

'you can find below function on stackoverflow
strPath = Left(myFolder, Len(myFolder) - Len(GetFilenameFromPath(myFolder)) - 1) 'file path ended with \
nejm = GetFilenameFromPath(myFolder) 'file name

'this is the place which is creating that "ini" file
Open strPath & "\" & "schema.ini" For Output As #1
Print #1, "[" & nejm & "]" & vbNewLine & "Format = Delimited(;)"
Close #1
```

After all processes You can just add:

```
Kill strPath & "\" & "schema.ini"
```